# Adding least squares and LMS lines to a plot

Tags: r, 3d, 2d, least-squares, lms

I have loaded the data set `Animals2` from the package `library (robustbase)`, and I am interested on working with the logarithm of these data.

```
library(robustbase)
x<-log(Animals2)
plot(x, main="Plot Animals2", col="darkgreen")
```

Now I need to add the least-squares line, the LMS line, and the line
of Siegel, by using different colours. Finally, I also wanted to show two plots with the estimated 2-dimensional densities. The first plot should be a 3D visualization of the density (I was trying to use command `persp`) and the second plot with the command `image` (applied to the
density estimate).

I am a bit stuck and would appreciate some help.

Comment: `abline()` will let you plot linear model lines in the scatterplot.  The `kde2d()` function from the `MASS` package calculates 2-D density estimates and you should then be able to use `persp()` and `image()` to make the plots.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong I am having trouble with the line of Siegel. I am using the following code but it doesnt work:   `install.packages("mblm")   library("mblm")
mblm(Animals2$body ~ Animals2$brain , repeated=TRUE)`

Comment: You should be able to do it with `mblm(body ~ brain, data=x, repeated=TRUE)`.  Just beware that when you do `plot(x)` it puts `brain` on the y-axis and `body` on the x-axis.  In your model, you've got it the other way around.  If you want `brain` to be the dependent variable, use `mblm(brain ~ body, ...)` otherwise, you should use `plot(body ~ brain, data=x)` to put `body` rather than `brain` on the y-axis.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Okay thank you very much I understand now. And which of the 3 the regression lines would you say is more suitable for the data?

Comment: The Least Squares line is drawn toward the cluster of three outliers.  To me, this makes it less suitable, but the other lines are discounting (down-weighting) those points, so the inferential qualities of those lines may be somewhat dubious.  The question of which line is most suitable is one that would be better posed to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `mblm()` does the Siegel model, you could use this:

```r
  library(robustbase)
  library(mblm)
  data(Animals2)
  x <- log(Animals2)
  plot(x, main="Plot Animals2", col="darkgreen")
  abline(lm(brain ~ body, data=x), col="red")
  abline(MASS::lqs(brain ~ body, data=x, method="lms"), col="blue")
  abline(mblm(brain ~ body, data=x, repeated=TRUE), col="black")
  legend("topleft", c("LM", "LMS", "Siegel"), 
         col = c("red", "blue", "black"), 
         lty = c(1,1,1), 
         inset=.01)
```

[image]

```r
d2 <- MASS::kde2d(x$body, x$brain)
persp(d2)
```

[image]

```r
image(d2, xlab="body", ylab="brain")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>